# I want to run google calendar Project on android emulator from google website. But it doesn't work

Tags: android, emulation

```
05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android/com.android.Calendar_googleActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:164)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:88)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:814)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.execute(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:182)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClient.executeUnparsed(GoogleClient.java:115)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest.executeUnparsed(JsonHttpRequest.java:112)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar$CalendarList$List.execute(Calendar.java:510)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.android.Calendar_googleActivity.onAuthToken(Calendar_googleActivity.java:267)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.android.Calendar_googleActivity.gotAccount(Calendar_googleActivity.java:118)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.android.Calendar_googleActivity.onCreate(Calendar_googleActivity.java:108)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)

05-08 11:04:12.336: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: what did you do?, what do you want to do?, what have you tried?

Comment: You're at risk for your question to be closed. Please add substance to your question (specific question, code, explanation of what you want to achieve, explanation of what you've tried, and explanation of what went wrong).

Answer (score 2):

```
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You've always been warned against doing networking on the UI thread as that could lead to UI lag and application not responding errors if the network operation is delayed.

In recent releases you are now actually prohibited - by the proactive error above - from attempting to 'get away with it'

So get your network usage off of the UI thread and you should be all set.  We do not need to discuss how to do that here - it's well covered in the documentation and previous questions.

Comment: I enter my account name and password to allow access to the account.
It shows "unfortunately, MY APP has stopped".How to do?

Comment: You have to redesign the code to move the network operations off the UI thread.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Android+network+UI+thread